# Plotting functions in webgl

Tags: webgl

Im starting to take a look at webgl. So far drawing shapes and lines is relatively easy. However i wouldnt know how to plot a function such as `y = sin(x)` or something more complex than that.

I can imagine how this could be done individually on the pixel level  by just figuring out the axis and then calculating which pixels to draw individually based on the scale.

How would you approach this problem using webgl? Is there some build in functionality i could use or should i alproach it on a per pixel basis?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: How would you plot something in canvas 2d? WebGL is no different, just lower level. You build a set of code functions to do the same things canvas 2d does and then you'd use those to plot your math functions with them